# What is the proper method for assigning multiple hierarchicalDataTemplates to a TreeView ItemTemplate?

Tags: c#, wpf, treeview, hierarchicaldatatemplate

I have three XML HierarchicalDataTemplates. They are loaded at runtime and then assigned to the TreeView.ItemTemplate. This is the code that I used, successfully, about six years ago on a similar project. Not only doesn't it work now (the original project still mysteriously works fine) but, frankly, I can't understand the code that I wrote six years ago or **why** it works! Here's the code snippet (OOB is the TreeView):

```
       //This is for dynamically building a treeview with templates from an XML file
        XmlTextReader xmlReader1 = new XmlTextReader("HierarchicalDataTemplate1.xml");
        HierarchicalDataTemplate hierarchicalDataTemplate1 = XamlReader.Load(xmlReader1) as HierarchicalDataTemplate;

        XmlTextReader xmlReader2 = new XmlTextReader("HierarchicalDataTemplate2.xml");
        HierarchicalDataTemplate hierarchicalDataTemplate2 = XamlReader.Load(xmlReader2) as HierarchicalDataTemplate;
        hierarchicalDataTemplate1.ItemTemplate = hierarchicalDataTemplate2;

        XmlTextReader xmlReader3 = new XmlTextReader("HierarchicalDataTemplate3.xml");
        HierarchicalDataTemplate hierarchicalDataTemplate3 = XamlReader.Load(xmlReader3) as HierarchicalDataTemplate;
        hierarchicalDataTemplate2.ItemTemplate = hierarchicalDataTemplate3;

        OOB.ItemTemplate = hierarchicalDataTemplate1;

        Thread updateThread = new Thread(new ParameterizedThreadStart(UpdateTree));
        updateThread.Start(this);
```

The TreeView (OOB) displays the first two levels of nodes correctly but not the third. Considering, I don't see how the third hierarchicalDataTemplate is ever assigned to OOB.ItemTemplate this isn't surprising (well, the surprise is why does it work correctly in the code I wrote six years ago).

Can anybody tell me how to correctly assign three separate XML hierarchicalDataTemplate files to a TreeView? Thanks!

Comment: If you have a working solution that uses the same code and a non-working one, then probably the best way is to try to **reduce** the working solution to a non-working step-by-step. Copy that working solution and start to remove anything that is not related to a new application - in the end you will either have something that will inexplicably work but at least can be used as a basis for a new application, or, most probably, you will find the missing piece that enabled that old application to work in the first place.

Comment: Well, I've done compares with a diff program and the relevant parts seem identical. What I can't understand is how hiearchicalDataTemplate3 is ever assigned to OOB.ItemTemplate.

Comment: Diff is one thing. Reduction is another - the reason it works may be in those parts you do not consider relevant.  And `hiearchicalDataTemplate3` seems to be assigned in `hierarchicalDataTemplate2.ItemTemplate = hierarchicalDataTemplate3;`.

Comment: Right, but how does hierarchicalDataTemplate2 get assigned to OOB.ItemTemplate after hierarchicalDataTemplate3 is assigned to hierarchicalDataTemplate2? That's what's got me stumped. And, yet, this is exactly the same code copy and pasted from the other (much larger) project that I wrote six years ago.

Comment: As far as I understand you have `OOB` with `ItemTemplate` set to `hierarchicalDataTemplate1` that has `ItemTemplate` set to `hierarchicalDataTemplate2` that has `ItemTemplate` set to `hierarchicalDataTemplate3`. In the end OOB has ItemTemplate that at the lowest level uses `hierarchicalDataTemplate3`. It seems pretty reasonable to me, though my WPF slightly rusted away with time.

Comment: Well, that's the code that worked before (six years ago). If I mess around with it (e.g. point OOB.ItemTemplate directly at hierarchicalDataTemplate2, it DOES show the lowest level nodes, but messes up on levels 1 and 2.

Answer (score 0):

This was not the problem. It was in the way the `HierarchicalDataTemplate` XML file was set up with the Xpath.